# Apache Reverse Proxy with "or" Statement

Tags: apache-httpd

I have my apache2 .conf file for my site. Is it possible to have an "or" statement, so that the user who wants to access the api have either the required IP OR the certificate? It looks like this at the moment.

```
    <LocationMatch ^/api/devices/.+/stuff$>
      SSLVerifyClient require
    </LocationMatch>

    <LocationMatch ^/api/devices/.+/otherStuff$>
      SSLVerifyClient require

    </LocationMatch>

#possible OR statement here?

        <LocationMatch "/(api|websocket|admin|consulting)">
                 <RequireAny>
                     #IPs
                     Require ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
                 </RequireAny>
         </LocationMatch>
```

Thanks!

Comment: See [Authorization providers for use with Require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#authzproviders). So I think you can use `Require ssl-verify-client <newline> Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and even remove `<RequireAny/>` as they are OR'ed by default.

Comment: @Freddy Thanks, but that doesnt work. When I put `Require ssl-verfify-client` under the IPs, I cant access the admin site and alle the other stuff when I comment out my IP (and also have a valid certificate). Do I need to do something else beside putting in that Require ssl-verify-client?